# Trying to create a new tab in chrome extension results in an infinite loop of new tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am trying to make a content script send a message to background script, after which background needs to create a new tab. I am able to send and receive the message, but when trying to create a new tab, I get an infinite loop in chrome of new tabs

content.js

```
function waitForElementToDisplay(
  selector,
  callback,
  checkFrequencyInMs,
  timeoutInMs
) {
  var startTimeInMs = Date.now();
  (function loopSearch() {
    if (document.querySelector(selector) != null) {
      callback();
      return;
    } else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (timeoutInMs && Date.now() - startTimeInMs > timeoutInMs) return;
        loopSearch();
      }, checkFrequencyInMs);
    }
  })();
}

waitForElementToDisplay(
  "#cq-cf-framewrapper",
  function () {
    console.log("element found");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ greeting: "hello" });
  },
  1000,
  9000
);
```

background.js (I need to first collect the tabs to the right of the active one, push them into an array before I create new tab)

```
const resolverUrl =
  "https://wwwperf.brandeuauthorlb.ford.com/cf#/etc/guxacc/tools/resource-resolver-tool.html";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

  if (request.greeting === "hello") {
    console.log("request received");
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      let activeIndex;
      var rightTabs = [];
      for (const tab of tabs) {
        // set the activeIndex so we wont have to run a loop on the tabs twice
        if (tab.active) {
          activeIndex = tab.index;
        }

        // tabs to the right of the active tab will have higher index
        if (typeof activeIndex !== "undefined" && tab.index > activeIndex) {
          // tabs is on the right of the active tab ... do whatever needed
          console.log(tab);
          if (tab.url.includes("/content/guxeu")) {
            rightTabs.push(tab);
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(rightTabs);
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: resolverUrl, active: false }, function (tab) {

        chrome.scripting
          .executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            files: ["scripts/resolver.js"],
          })
          .then(() => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, request);
          });
      });
    });
    return true;
  }
});
```

Hoping you can detect my mistake, thanks in advance